# Помогите разобраться, чего так происходит?

Tags: java

```
if (4 != 4) {
  System.out.println("4 == 4!");
}
```

Чего в данном коде выражение равняется `false`? Из за представления чисел или другой вариант?

Comment: `4 != 4` - false. Глядите, если я скажу, яблоко не есть яблоко, вы наверное ответите : "Нет, яблоко - это яблоко." Тоже самое и тут, если взять утверждение, что яблоко есть яблоко, то ответ будет: "Да, яблоко - это яблоко". В первом случае наше нет - `false`, а во втором да - `true`.

Answer (score 7):

С представлением чисел все ок, это примитивы, их так и нужно сравнивать. False будет, потому что if ждет boolean, ну то есть правда/неправда. То есть если написано if (4 != 4), это понимается так: правда ли, что 4 != 4?